# SDL won't display image in window when called from class

Tags: c++, image, class, header-files, sdl-2

I'm trying to organize my code a bit more, so I tried putting the SDL2 code used for displaying windows/images into a class. The window opens, the code runs successfully, and the image seems to be loading fine, -but **the image will not appear when the code is arranged in a class like this. Why is this happening?**

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "display.h"

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Surface* image = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
        return false;

    Display display;
    display.loadImage("image.bmp");

    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }

        display.applySurface(0, 0, image, display.windowSurface);
        display.update();
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

**display.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Display
{
public:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Surface* windowSurface;

    Display();
    SDL_Surface* loadImage(std::string fileName);
    void applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr);
    void update();
    ~Display();
private:
    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 612;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 632;
    const int SCREEN_BPP = 2;
};
```

**display.cpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include "display.h"

Display::Display()
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error: SDL_CreateWindow failed." << std::endl;

    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if (windowSurface == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error: Window surface is null." << std::endl;
}

SDL_Surface* Display::loadImage(std::string fileName)
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(fileName.c_str());

    if (loadedImage == NULL)
        std::cout << "Loaded image = NULL" << std::endl;
    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        optimizedImage = SDL_ConvertSurface(loadedImage, windowSurface->format, 0);

        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

        if (optimizedImage == NULL)
            std::cout << "Optimized image = NULL" << std::endl;
        if (optimizedImage != NULL)
            SDL_SetColorKey(optimizedImage, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(optimizedImage->format, 255, 255, 255));
    }

    return optimizedImage;
}


void Display::applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect *clip)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

void Display::update()
{
    if (SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window) == -1)
        std::cout << "Error: SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() failed." << std::endl;
}

Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(windowSurface);
    windowSurface = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.cpp your image is empty because you didn't use the return image :

```
image = display.loadImage("image.bmp");
```